# Register an URL protocol / URI scheme to an application installed by Install4j?

Tags: install4j, uri-scheme

We provide a cross-platform installer for one of our applications through Install4j. We would like to be able to register the installed application to an URL protocol. Can that be done with Install4j?

A bit of background: our application is an XMPP client. We would like to have it started when a user invokes an URL that starts with "[xmpp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5122)". This is similar to how a browser is opened when clicking on a link that starts with "http" and how a mail client is opened when clicking on a link that starts with "mailto".

There appear to be [numerous, platform-specific solutions](https://wiki.xmpp.org/web/XMPP_URIs), but as our application is a cross-platform application, we'd like to be able to have a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of install4j 6.1.5 this is not a feature in install4j. It's in our issuer tracker, though and I have added your feedback to the issue.

---

**Update 2019-11-26**

Since install4j 8, the "Register a URL handler" action provides this functionality for Windows, macOS and Linux.

Comment: Can Unsubscribe to that issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, our issue tracker is not public.

Comment: Dare I ask for an ETA? 

Comment: Unfortunately I have no ETA for it.

Comment: Gearing up towards a new release of our software - would be nice to be able to include this feature. Has there been any progress on this in the past few months?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries - I can see how this wouldn't be the highest priority issue. I'll keep poking for updates periodically, if you don't mind.

Comment: Did you by any chance add this feature in Install4j 7? We would also want this ability to register a custom protocol handler on Windows for our application (Oxygen XML Editor).

Comment: No, but we tentatively plan to do it for install4j 8 later this year

Comment: It's about time for my yearly check-in on this :) Any news on the horizon?

Comment: Yes. it's implemented in install4j 8. I'll update the answer.